# can i submit form with submit button and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

My question might be basic but i want it to clarify. i have one html form. it contain 2 submit button and some links. on click of one of the link i am trying to submit the form by java-script but not able to do so. but when i make all the button as normal button and submit the form by JavaScript then i am able to submit the form by link too.

Now my question is - if we have submit button in the form then can we submit the form by java-script too?

Comment: Submit button automatically submits the form only you should have proper form tab on the page and action attribute

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a submit button to submit a form - period. You can submit a form by javascript regardless of whether or not you have any fields or buttons at all, all you need is a form element.

My magic crystal ball tells me your form submits just fine, but your serverside script was written poorly and depends on the name/value of a submit button being sent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, use the `onsubmit` event and then submit the form use javascript.

For example use jQuery:

```
$('#your_form').on('submit', function() {
  if (/**some condition**/) {
    $(this).submit(); 
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you submit your form with a link, i suppose you use this kind of code :

```
<a href="link" onclick="form.submit();">Submit my form</a>
```

This is wrong because you submit the form and then you go on the link, you have to put "return false;" after your submit():

```
<a href="link" onclick="form.submit();return false;">Submit my form</a>
```